# How do I disable tanks with the AT rifle?

Tags: red-orchestra-2

I've been playing an anti-tank recently. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be that much documentation on how to use the AT rifles, and the game itself offers precious little feedback.

So far the most detailed and readable schematics I've found are the ones on [Tripwire's own wiki](http://wiki.tripwireinteractive.com/index.php?title=RO2_Tanks), but they don't list all the targetable systems.

I suppose this question can be split into three:

1. Where are all the weak spots on both the Soviet and German tanks?
2. What effect does disabling each of them have?
3. How do I tell whether my hit disabled (not just hit/damaged) something important?

**My own findings so far. Some are based on various guides, others my own.**

AT rifles lose effectiveness over range, but they still work at ranges most combat takes place in the game (150 metres or so). Angle of attack is also important. Hitting an armour plate at 90 degrees can, in theory, pierce it, while anything under 45 will probably ricochet even off an unarmoured surface.

Tiny sprays of spark are shots that don't penetrate. Medium-sized puffs of smoke mean something was damaged. Large explosions are just explosions, but strangely enough, they don't seem fatal. A crew member's death is indicated by a large spray of blood, but I've only seen that happen from other tank shots.

A hit that damages anything at all definitely draws the tank's attention to you, allowing other AT soldiers a clearer shot.

An obvious weak spot is the engine: hitting it once or twice is enough to blow up the tank. But that's only possible from behind.

Tracks are exposed most of the time. Hitting the front and rear wheels on each side messes with the tank's mobility, but cannot destroy it.

When all else fails, shooting near the centre of the tracks seems to do some damage, but can take anywhere from 4 to 20+ shots to score a kill.

Also, I scored kills firing on these spots:
Pz.Kpfw. IV:
From the front, right in the centre of its hull. Was already heavily damaged by a friendly tank.
Slightly to the side, base of the main gun. Did I hit a shell?

Answer (score -1):

Think like how it worked in real life. The AT rifle in the game is a 54 caliber that can punch through thin tank armour. Note that I said THIN armour.

Tank armour in RO2 is pretty well done. Trying to shoot the front of a tank with your AT rifle will do literally nothing as the bullet bounces off the thick, slanted armour. If you wish to do any real damage with the AT rifle, aim at the caterpillar tracks under the tank. Hitting them can break them, and once theyre broken the tank is immobilized!

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to provide any information about the game mechanics which isn't already mentioned in the question.